# 'rU' mode for StringIO (new-line character seen in unquoted field)

Tags: python, csv, gzip, stringio

I am trying to parse gzip files line by line :

```
with gzip.open(obj.get()['Body'])as f:

    for line in f:
        line=StringIO(line.decode("utf-8"))
        line=csv.reader(line,delimiter=',')

        for line1 in line:

         #some logic
```

But for some of the files I have error:

```
new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

When I try to open in newlline mode:

```
csv.reader(open(line, 'rU'), delimiter=',')
```

I have:

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO
```

I want all fields, which contain '\r' to be in that field as part of string value.
How this can be resolved?

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: I use version 3.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, which avoids using the `csv.reader` and `StringIO` modules:

```
with gzip.open(obj.get()['Body'])as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.decode("utf-8").split(',')

        for line1 in line:
            #some logic
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I use csv reader, cause it parse my data correctly. I have commas inside quoted filelds and that is why .split(',') doesnt work for me

Comment: A [mcve] with complete example file would be useful to understand

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=io#io.StringIO if you pass a second parameter as None it should recognize all newlines

Comment: Thank you!I thought it  worked, but it turned out, rows whose fields contained '\r' inside were removed after i set newline parameter to None. And I need all rows in my resultset